# Multiprocessing with dynamically loaded modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-importlib

I have some code that is executed on about 15000 inputs.
Each input consists of a directory path, and path to a python script that should be executed for that directory. for example say there`s a script example.py which is

```
def get_features(path):
    results = []
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,d):
            results.append(do_some_stuff(os.path.join(path,f)))
    return results
```

There can be anywhere from 2 to ~10 different scripts like example.py... In my program I load these scripts like this:

```
for script_name, script_path in scripts:
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('{}.script'.format(script_name), script_path)
    modules[script_name] = importlib.util.module_from_specs(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(modules[script_name])
```

Then I match each directory path from the input to the appropriate script in a list of tuples, and finally call the script for each directory in a loop

```
for dir_path, loaded_script in work_list:
    result = loaded_script.get_features(dir_path)
    results_set.update(result)
```

This loop is taking ages, so I wanted to use a multiprocessing pool to speed things up, say like this

```
def worker(path, func):
    return func(path)
p = multiprocessing.Pool(6)
all_results = p.starmap(worker, work_list)
results_set = set([item for res_list in all_results for item in res_list])
```

But I can't do this since a module (second object in each tuple in the arguments list) is not picklable, and I would get a PicklingError...
I Thought of passing the path to the script instead of the loaded module to the worker method, but since the number of invocations of the method is much much larger than the number of different scripts, this seems very wasteful to load the module again each time...
Is there a way to pass a module to a worker method for multiprocessing?